# Как правильно переопределить размер модального окна в Bootstrap 2.3.2?

Tags: bootstrap

Есть правило для модального окна, где указана его ширина в `560px`, если поменять это свойство в большую сторону, то размер модального окна изменится но оно будет не по центру, а расширится вправо. Каким образом задать новый размер окна и так чтобы ничего не сломалось?

```
div.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 1050;
  width: 560px;
  margin-left: -280px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  *border: 1px solid #999;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  -moz-background-clip: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  outline: none;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Вижу зависимость правил:

```
width: 560px;
margin-left: -280px;
```

Если например поменять так:

```
width: 700px;
margin-left: -350px;
```

То для десктопной версии все ок, а вот при респонсиве до мобильной версии, все плохо, ломается и съезжает теперь влево и пропадает контент и часть модального окна.

**UPDATE**

Оказалось что проблема воспроизводится в браузере Google Chrome, в других браузерах вроде как нету проблемы...

Comment: width modal px  и margin-left: -(width modal/2)px

Comment: @soledar10 В том то и дело, не помогает для мобильной версии ломается.

Comment: а прописать в @media запросах для нужных значений?

Comment: @soledar10 Если бы я знал где что прописать я бы не задавал вопрос...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В моем случае проблема решилась следующим кодом.

```
div.modal {
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: -40%;    
}

@media (max-width:767px) {
  div.modal {
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Приблизительно так

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/hd7p57nb/2/)

```css
@import url('https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css');

.modal {  
  width: 700px;
  margin-left: -350px; 
}

@media (max-width:767px) {
  .modal {    
    top: 20px; left: 20px; right: 20px;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">demo modal</a>

<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade">

  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h3>Modal header</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    Modal body
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Эти медиа правила поумолчанию прописаны и так! Оказалось проблема воспроизводится в браузере гугл хром... А в FF проблемы нету.

Comment: Chrome Версия 53.0.2785.143 m (64-bit) - все работает

Comment: Тем не менее у меня на Версия 53.0.2785.143 m работало криво.